# How can I get Excel to release its lock on another Excel file I've accessed using ADO?

Tags: excel, ado, excel-2003, vba

I'm using a VBA macro in an Excel 2003 document to query another Excel 2003 document via ADO. The code looks something like this:

```
  Dim vRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset

  vWorkbookConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\SomeExcelFile.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"

  Set vRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset

  Call vRecordSet.Open(Source:=strSQl, ActiveConnection:=vWorkbookConnectionString, _
    CursorType:=adOpenForwardOnly, LockType:=adLockReadOnly, Options:=adCmdText)
```

`vRecordSet` is later used to create a PivotCache.

My goal is to delete the file that is the source of this RecordSet (C:\SomeExcelFile.xls in the example above) when the user closes the workbook from which this code is run.

The file gets locked when this ADO query is run, and it doesn't seem to get released until after the Workbook is closed. Calling `vRecordSet.Close` does not release it.

Is it possible to force Excel to release its lock on this file so that I can delete it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding the following after your `vRecordSet.Close` call to see if it makes a difference:

```
Set vRecordSet = Nothing
```

Comment: I'm rather new to VBA, and I don't really understand what benefit this would provide. Are you saying that forcing the RecordSet to be garbage-collected might cause the lock on the file to be released?

Comment: I've just seen situations where setting it to nothing can make a difference. It may or may not help in your case. Did you try it? What was the outcome?

Comment: It works! Seems like GCing the Recordset does *something* that Closing it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Untested Voodoo: use a variable to hold the ADODB.Connection, pass this to open, close both the recordset and the connection.